# Restoring MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql

By mistake I added foreign key "ON DELETE CASCADE" to one table. So some records from are gone after some time, but I made backup of it before. How can I restore deleted records from backup, without overriding other data. I need just to add missing records to table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: What keeps you from applying the backup?

Comment: Kindly ask the dba to restore the data!

Answer (score 0):

From the backup just take only those tables and import into a temp table then select(required records) and insert into the original table by or just from the backup keep only the tables and the deleted records by editing manually then run the backup.